# What is the proper way to update an object data in MongoDB when using variable keys for the object values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, backend

First time posting here.

I have a Mongoose Schema and Model shown below:

```
const DataSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name:{type: String, default: ""},
    task: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {}}
  },
  { timestamps: true, _id: true, minimize: false, strict: false }
);

const Data = mongoose.model("Data", DataSchema);
```

Now when a user profile is created using the “name” parameter I would get the following response as an example:

```
{"success: true, "data":[{"name":"Eminem","_id":"5ee8468316a2ea32bcfbf411","task":{},"createdAt":"2020-06-16T04:11:47.441Z","updatedAt":"2020-06-16T04:11:47.441Z","__v":0}]}
```

My next action is to update the task object based on user’s input for the “taskName”. For example: if a user inputs “work” as “taskName”, I want the task object to be updated as `"task": {work:{}}.`

For that I used the method below but it never updates the “task” object. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
var id = "5ee8468316a2ea32bcfbf411"
var taskName="work"
var key = 'task.'+taskName
var push = {}
push[key]={}

Data.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:id}, push, (err,data)=> {
      if(err) throw err
  }
);
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
let id = "5ee8468316a2ea32bcfbf411"
let taskName="work"
Data.findByIdAndUpdate(id,
      {$set:{task:{[taskName]:{}}}, 
      (err,data)=> {
      if(err) throw err
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I was stuck on this for a couple of days. This works perfect and the expression is clearer than my approach.

Comment: Hi again, this worked except for when I try to add a second item later like `"home":{}` it is overwriting the first item(`"work":{}`). Is there a way not to overwrite the first item when adding a second item? @user9879287

Comment: Never mind! I used the following to append to the object without overwriting it.

`Data.findById(id, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    Data.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: {task: {...data.task, [taskID]:{}}}}, (err,data)=> {
      if(err) throw err
      console.log(data)
  }
    );
    return res.json({ success: true, data: data });
});  
 
});`